# Testing a CallBack function in a function which get triggered forButton Onclick using jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, spy

I have a React child component which has button

```
export function Banner({argumentSetter}){
function handleOnClick(){
  argumentSetter(argument.READ);
}
return(
<div>
  <Button onClick={handleOnClick}>
    <Icon name="delete" type="filled">
      Discard
    </Icon>
  </Button>
</div>
)
}
```

And I have my argumentSetter in my parent component defined as following,

```
const [argument,setArgument] = useState<Argument>(argument.EDIT);
argumentSetter = useCallBack((val)=>{
setArgument(val);
},[argument]);

return(
  <div>
    <Banner argumentSetter={argumentSetter}/>
  </div>
)
```

How to get 100% test coverage using jest.

Comment: Not sure if there's a lot of use of `useCallback` in the code above. Every time `argument` updates, `argumentSetter` will update too. It might just make sense to directly use `setArgument` as a prop to `argumentSetter` because it seems like over optimization might actually slow down performance.

Comment: I am setting the value of argumentSetter in child component and sending it back to parent component, that is the reason I wrote it in that way, iam new to jest, not able to test it. Can you help me with testing?. I dont mind for performance right now because iam worried only about testing the child component.

Comment: What library are you using for UI testing in Jest?

Comment: I am using Enzyme

Comment: Are you planning to test the parent component as well, or just the child component, which is `Banner`?

Comment: I want to test only the child component for now

Comment: Does the answer work?

Comment: Yep, Thank you so much, you saved lot of my work

Comment: Could you rate the answer and resolve the question!

Answer (score 0):

To test the banner, your code should be like the following

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import { Banner } from "./Banner.js";
import { argument } from "./arguments.js";

it("Button click leads to argument.READ", async () => {
  let promiseResolve = null;
  const argPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    promiseResolve = resolve;
  });
  const argumentSetter = (arg) => promiseResolve(arg);
  const banner = mount(<Banner argumentSetter={argumentSetter} />);
  banner.find("button").simulate("click");
  const newArg = await argPromise;
  expect(newArg).toEqual(argument.READ);
});
```

### Explanation:

We create an externally fulfillable promise variable, called `argPromise` which will resolve when `promiseResolve` is called, which is called when the `argumentSetter` is called. Hence, when the button click is simulated, it will resolve the updated argument to `newArg` variable (which should be `argument.READ`), and hence you can test if it matches your expectation.

This should hence cover all lines of your Banner component during testing.